# I'm trying to build a min-heap array from another array of frequencies

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm trying to build a min-heap in an array from an array where the index corresponds to an ASCII value and the value at that index represents a frequency.

I then use these find min functions to retrieve the minimum value

```
int findMinIndex(int *x){
    int a = findMaxValue(x);
    int i = 0;
    int index;
    for(i = 0;i < 128;i++){
        if(a > x[i] && x[i] != 0){
            a = x[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}


int findMinValue(int *x){
int a = findMaxValue(x);
int i = 0;
for(i = 0;i < 128;i++){
    if(a > x[i] && x[i] != 0){
        a = x[i];
        x[i] = 0;
    }
}
return a;
```

}

After i retrieve those two values, i attempt to enter them into an array of heap objects

```
class node{
public:
    int occurances;
    char val;
};
```

for some reason when i do this, it only seems to fill the array partially correctly then fills the rest with the max frequency repeatedly.

when i use cout to see the array i end up with this

```
heap[1] = 1
heap[2] = 2
heap[3] = 6
heap[4] = 8
heap[0] = 36
heap[0] = 36
heap[0] = 36
heap[0] = 36
```

i can't really figure out what this means, or why this is happening.
so how can i fix it to where i end up with a min heap in array form?

Comment: You would really benefit from the `<algorithm>` library to do all these things for you.

Comment: From the output you posted, it appears at you're just repeating the output for `heap[0]`. Is this a typo or is that your actual output?

Comment: Also, there appear to be cases where `findMinIndex` could potentially return `index` without ever initializing it?

Comment: It's my actual output.  I used a loop to repeatedly find the min value, then index, then set that value to 0 so i ignore it the next time around and keep doing that over and over.

Comment: also, my professor is kinda weird about using built in functions that do the sorting and counting for me. He prefers me to write all my own stuff, which sucks so much because i know there are such easier ways to do this.